# How to specify primary key in a through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an implementation for a graph node class that I'd like to have function as a directed acyclic graph.

The associations are roughly as follows

```
class Node
  has_many :edges

  has_many :parents,
           :foreign_key => 'parent_id',
           :through => :edge

  has_many :parent_edges,
           :foreign_key => 'child_id',
           :class_name => 'Edge',
           :dependent => :destroy

  # similar for children
end

class Edge
  belongs_to :parent,
             :class_name => 'Node'

  # similar for child

  has_many :edge_properties
end
```

When I try to grab a relation of parent nodes, the generated query still uses 
`node_id` as the primary key.

```
SELECT `nodes`.* 
FROM   `nodes` 
       INNER JOIN `edges` 
               ON `nodes`.`id` = 
                  `edges`.`parent_id` 
WHERE  `edges`.`node_id` = 16             # where clause uses node_id, should be child_id
ORDER  BY `nodes`.`name` ASC
```

What can I do to change that query to use `child_id` in the where clause?

Comment: Did you try to put `:foreign_key => :child_id` in the Edge `belongs_to :parent` line? Also: can you show us the Rails code that generates that SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution (also TIL :through option can specify another association)

```
 has_many :parent_edges,
          :foreign_key => 'child_id',
          :class_name => 'Edge',
          :dependent => :destroy

 has_many :parents,
          :source => 'parent',
          :through => :parent_edges  # using another association
```